# Задать мультииндекс Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Пожалуйста помогите привести в порядок датафрейм.

---

Исходный датафрейм:

```
                     price   qty  side  status                 tradeID
 date
 2018-09-03 17:00:00  7282.5  10.0   Buy  filled  71ZNeXwSQUqkxhKR9trvrQ
 2018-09-05 11:00:00  7111.0  10.0  Sell  filled  71ZNeXwSQUqkxhKR9trvrQ
 2018-09-08 10:00:00  6448.0  10.0   Buy  filled  WYgKLRv+Q9CuXic4FNEh0A
 2018-09-08 18:00:00  6377.0  10.0  Sell  filled  WYgKLRv+Q9CuXic4FNEh0A
 2018-09-09 14:00:00  6376.5  10.0   Buy  filled  /6WmcfJ1QcWWwPcwkXeoSw
```

Требуется объедение по tradeID. Тоесть что бы строки с одинаковым tradeID были объедененны по этому значения.
Пример нужного итогового датафрейма.

```
                                             price   qty  side  status                 
 tradeID                date
 71ZNeXwSQUqkxhKR9trvrQ 2018-09-03 17:00:00  7282.5  10.0   Buy  filled 
                        2018-09-05 11:00:00  7111.0  10.0  Sell  filled  
 WYgKLRv+Q9CuXic4FNEh0A 2018-09-08 10:00:00  6448.0  10.0   Buy  filled  
                        2018-09-08 18:00:00  6377.0  10.0  Sell  filled  
 /6WmcfJ1QcWWwPcwkXeoSw 2018-09-09 14:00:00  6376.5  10.0   Buy  filled
```

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [DataFrame.set_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
In [251]: df2 = df.set_index(['tradeID', df.index])

In [252]: df2
Out[252]:
                                             price   qty  side  status
tradeID                date
71ZNeXwSQUqkxhKR9trvrQ 2018-09-03 17:00:00  7282.5  10.0   Buy  filled
                       2018-09-05 11:00:00  7111.0  10.0  Sell  filled
WYgKLRv+Q9CuXic4FNEh0A 2018-09-08 10:00:00  6448.0  10.0   Buy  filled
                       2018-09-08 18:00:00  6377.0  10.0  Sell  filled
/6WmcfJ1QcWWwPcwkXeoSw 2018-09-09 14:00:00  6376.5  10.0   Buy  filled
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, именно я это я и пытался сделать =)

Comment: @DmitrySharko, пожалуйста :)