# Как добавить в датафрейм столбец, с выполненной калькуляцией? Обрабатывая данные внутри мультииндекса

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, multi-index

Еще один вопрос, в продолжение [вчерашнего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/964195/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-pandas/964197?noredirect=1#comment1614974_964197). Мне нужно посчитать профит по каждой отдельной сделке (`tradeID`). (`tradeID` и `date` - индексы)
Вопрос - как **грамотно** добавить в датафрейм столбец `profit`, с выполненной калькуляцией (`sell - buy` просто например...)
Из-за маленького опыта я начал писать какие то ужасные вложенные циклы для этого. Но уверен что с Pandas все может быть проще. Пожалуйста подскажите направление движения.

---

Исходный датафрейм:

```
                                             price   qty  side  status                 
 tradeID                date
 71ZNeXwSQUqkxhKR9trvrQ 2018-09-03 17:00:00  7282.5  10.0   Buy  filled 
                        2018-09-05 11:00:00  7111.0  10.0  Sell  filled  
 WYgKLRv+Q9CuXic4FNEh0A 2018-09-08 10:00:00  6448.0  10.0   Buy  filled  
                        2018-09-08 18:00:00  6377.0  10.0  Sell  filled  
 /6WmcfJ1QcWWwPcwkXeoSw 2018-09-09 14:00:00  6376.5  10.0   Buy  filled
```

Хотелось бы получить что то такое:

```
                                             price   qty  side  status    profit                
 tradeID                date
 71ZNeXwSQUqkxhKR9trvrQ 2018-09-03 17:00:00  7282.5  10.0   Buy  filled 
                        2018-09-05 11:00:00  7111.0  10.0  Sell  filled  -171.5
 WYgKLRv+Q9CuXic4FNEh0A 2018-09-08 10:00:00  6448.0  10.0   Buy  filled  
                        2018-09-08 18:00:00  6377.0  10.0  Sell  filled  -71
 /6WmcfJ1QcWWwPcwkXeoSw 2018-09-09 14:00:00  6376.5  10.0   Buy  filled
```

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Как считать доход если дата продажи отличается от даты покупки для одного и того же tradeID?

Comment: @MaxU По сути даты не особо важны, как я понимаю. Нужно просто внутри каждого tradeID выполнить Sell - Buy при соответствующих price, и записать профит по данному tradeID в столбец profit. Я начал писать цикл в котором перебираю каждый tradeID, потом в нем каждую строку, и с помощью if выполнять калькуляцию. Такой способ показался мне ужасным, зная возможности Pandas. Но как сделать аккуратнее не знаю =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такой вариант устроит?:

```
df['profit']= df.groupby(level=[0]).transform(lambda x: x.shift(-1) - x)['price']
print(df)

                                             price   qty  side  status  profit
71ZNeXwSQUqkxhKR9trvrQ 2018-09-03 17:00:00  7282.5  10.0   Buy  filled  -171.5
                       2018-09-05 11:00:00  7111.0  10.0  Sell  filled     NaN
WYgKLRv+Q9CuXic4FNEh0A 2018-09-08 10:00:00  6448.0  10.0   Buy  filled   -71.0
                       2018-09-08 18:00:00  6377.0  10.0  Sell  filled     NaN
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Да думаю, о решение в таком духе я и спрашивал, что бы избавиться от циклов. Иду в документацию читать что к чему. Спасибо еще раз!

Answer (score 4):

Еще один рабочий вариант:

```
In [277]: df['profit'] = (df.sort_values(['tradeID','date', 'side'])
                            .groupby('tradeID')
                            ['price'].diff())

In [278]: df
Out[278]:
                                             price   qty  side  status  profit
tradeID                date
71ZNeXwSQUqkxhKR9trvrQ 2018-09-03 17:00:00  7282.5  10.0   Buy  filled     NaN
                       2018-09-05 11:00:00  7111.0  10.0  Sell  filled  -171.5
WYgKLRv+Q9CuXic4FNEh0A 2018-09-08 10:00:00  6448.0  10.0   Buy  filled     NaN
                       2018-09-08 18:00:00  6377.0  10.0  Sell  filled   -71.0
/6WmcfJ1QcWWwPcwkXeoSw 2018-09-09 14:00:00  6376.5  10.0   Buy  filled     NaN
```

Comment: Большое, спасибо! Выглядит лаконичнее. Оба ответа очень помогли с решением проблемы. Думаю sort_values(['tradeID','date', 'side']) важно выполнить, что бы избежать возможных ошибок. Спасибо за помощь!