# Работа с apply и transform в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, анализ-данных

В продолжение [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/964392/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%86-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5/964437#964437) . Теперь пробую осветить проблему максимально широко.

- **Исходный датафрейм:**

```py
                                               price   qty  side  status                 
 tradeID                date
 71ZNeXwSQUqkxhKR9trvrQ 2018-09-03 17:00:00  7282.5  10.0   Buy  filled 
                        2018-09-05 11:00:00  7111.0  10.0  Sell  filled  
 WYgKLRv+Q9CuXic4FNEh0A 2018-09-08 10:00:00  6448.0  10.0   Buy  filled  
                        2018-09-08 18:00:00  6377.0  10.0  Sell  filled  
 /6WmcfJ1QcWWwPcwkXeoSw 2018-09-09 14:00:00  6376.5  10.0   Buy  filled
```

Я хочу применять различные формулы (например подсчет прибыли и пр.) и заполнять исходный датафрейм. Группируя обрабатываемые данные с помощью groupby('tradeID'). Например для подсчета профита были предложены два отличных варианта.

- **1 Вариант (от @MaxU):**

```py
    In [277]: df['profit'] = (df.sort_values(['tradeID','date', 'side'])
                                .groupby('tradeID')
                                ['price'].diff())

    In [278]: df
    Out[278]:
                                                 price   qty  side  status  profit
    tradeID                date
    71ZNeXwSQUqkxhKR9trvrQ 2018-09-03 17:00:00  7282.5  10.0   Buy  filled     NaN
                           2018-09-05 11:00:00  7111.0  10.0  Sell  filled  -171.5
    WYgKLRv+Q9CuXic4FNEh0A 2018-09-08 10:00:00  6448.0  10.0   Buy  filled     NaN
                           2018-09-08 18:00:00  6377.0  10.0  Sell  filled   -71.0
    /6WmcfJ1QcWWwPcwkXeoSw 2018-09-09 14:00:00  6376.5  10.0   Buy  filled     NaN
```

- **2 Вариант(От @strawdog):**

```py
    df['profit']= df.groupby(level=[0]).transform(lambda x: x.shift(-1) - x)['price']
    print(df)

                                                 price   qty  side  status  profit
    71ZNeXwSQUqkxhKR9trvrQ 2018-09-03 17:00:00  7282.5  10.0   Buy  filled  -171.5
                           2018-09-05 11:00:00  7111.0  10.0  Sell  filled     NaN
    WYgKLRv+Q9CuXic4FNEh0A 2018-09-08 10:00:00  6448.0  10.0   Buy  filled   -71.0
                           2018-09-08 18:00:00  6377.0  10.0  Sell  filled     NaN
```

Но такие способы не подходят, если мы имеем несколько строк, где side==Sell(или Buy). Я не понимаю как использовать выбор по значению столбца в таких условиях. Я пробовал, что то вроде `self.df['profit'] = df.sort_values(['tradeID','date', 'side'])['price'].groupby('tradeID').apply(lambda x: x['price'][x['side']=='Sell'].mean() - x['price'][x['side']=='Buy'].mean())` Но получаю те или иные ошибки при подобных попытках, из-за не понимая принципа работы.

**Вопрос: Как провести подсчет прибыли внутри каждого `tradeID` на примере усложненного датафрейма (среднее арифметическое по *Sell* минус среднее арифметическое по *Buy*)? Столбцами `qty, status, date` можно пренебречь.**

- **Усложненный(новый) датафрейм:**

```py
                                                 price   qty  side  status                 
     tradeID                date
     71ZNeXwSQUqkxhKR9trvrQ 2018-09-03 17:00:00  7282.5  10.0   Buy  filled 
                            2018-09-05 11:00:00  7111.0  5.0  Sell  filled
                            2018-09-05 11:30:00  7200.0  5.0  Sell  filled
     WYgKLRv+Q9CuXic4FNEh0A 2018-09-08 10:00:00  6448.0  5.0   Buy  filled 
                            2018-09-08 10:02:00  6460.0  5.0   Buy  filled
                            2018-09-08 18:00:00  6500.0  10.0  Sell  filled
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то нужно сначала сгруппировать датафрейм по столбцам **"tradeID"** и **"side"** и применить `mean()` к столбцу **"price"**:

```
(df.groupby(['tradeID', 'side'])
   ['price'].mean())
```

Получим:

```
tradeID                 side
71ZNeXwSQUqkxhKR9trvrQ  Buy     7282.5
                        Sell    7155.5
WYgKLRv+Q9CuXic4FNEh0A  Buy     6454.0
                        Sell    6500.0
```

И далее нужно сгруппировать этот результат по **"tradeID"** и посчитать разницу. С использованием предыдущего куска кода:

```
(df.groupby(['tradeID', 'side']) 
   ['price'].mean()
   .groupby('tradeID').diff()
   .to_frame()
   .rename(columns={'price': 'profit'}))
```

Результат:

```
                                  profit
               tradeID    side  
71ZNeXwSQUqkxhKR9trvrQ     Buy       NaN
                          Sell    -127.0
WYgKLRv+Q9CuXic4FNEh0A     Buy       NaN
                          Sell      46.0
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь! Теперь я вроде понял как работает groupby() по нескольким столбцам. Всем благодарен от души, как всегда =)

Answer (score 4):

Решение в стиле "PIVOT":

```
res = (df.pivot_table(index='tradeID', columns='side', 
                      values='price', aggfunc='mean')
         .eval("profit = Sell - Buy"))
```

Результат:

```
In [397]: res
Out[397]:
side                       Buy    Sell  profit
tradeID
71ZNeXwSQUqkxhKR9trvrQ  7282.5  7155.5  -127.0
WYgKLRv+Q9CuXic4FNEh0A  6454.0  6500.0    46.0
```

Comment: это офигенно просто

Comment: Это жестко, eval() мужицкая функция)))

Answer (score 2):

Если честно, то вариант моего коллеги мне больше нравится из-за своей наглядности.
в вашем случае я бы предложил сделать так:

## 1 - меняем знак поля price в зависимости от значения side

```
df.loc[df["side"] == 'Sell', 'price'] *= -1

                                             price   qty  side  status
tradeID                date                                           
71ZNeXwSQUqkxhKR9trvrQ 2018-09-03 17:00:00  7282.5  10.0   Buy  filled
                       2018-09-05 11:00:00 -7111.0  10.0  Sell  filled
                       2018-09-05 11:00:00 -7050.0  10.0  Sell  filled
WYgKLRv+Q9CuXic4FNEh0A 2018-09-08 10:00:00  6448.0  10.0   Buy  filled
                       2018-09-08 18:00:00 -6377.0  10.0  Sell  filled
                       2018-09-08 18:00:00 -6200.0  10.0  Sell  filled
```

## 2 - делаем кумулятивное суммирование по группам:

```
df['profit'] = (df.sort_values(['tradeID','date', 'side'])
                                .groupby('tradeID')
                                ['price'].cumsum())

                                             price   qty  side  status  profit
tradeID                date                                                   
71ZNeXwSQUqkxhKR9trvrQ 2018-09-03 17:00:00  7282.5  10.0   Buy  filled  7282.5
                       2018-09-05 11:00:00 -7111.0  10.0  Sell  filled   171.5
                       2018-09-05 11:00:00 -7050.0  10.0  Sell  filled -6878.5
WYgKLRv+Q9CuXic4FNEh0A 2018-09-08 10:00:00  6448.0  10.0   Buy  filled  6448.0
                       2018-09-08 18:00:00 -6377.0  10.0  Sell  filled    71.0
                       2018-09-08 18:00:00 -6200.0  10.0  Sell  filled -6129.0
```

## Update

забыл добавить - финальные  значения по tradeID можно получить потом так:

```
df.groupby('tradeID').nth(-1)["profit"]

    tradeID
71ZNeXwSQUqkxhKR9trvrQ   -6878.5
WYgKLRv+Q9CuXic4FNEh0A   -6129.0
Name: profit, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за Ваш ответ. Но это немного не то(нужно среднее арифметическое, а суммирования не достаточно), @Andrey, в ответе ниже, привел пример нужного решения. Кстати, в процессе, я тоже размышлял навесить минусы на прайс по Sell в какой то момент =)

Comment: Да, у меня из головы вылетело про среднее арифметическое. я почему-то решил, что нужна простая сумма